# display data according to 1st dropdown select on 2nd dropdown in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have 3 dropdowns.
One for city, second for area,3rd for doctor specialization.
When i clicking on city 2nd dropdown should get all area related city, then 3rd should store corresponding specialization of that area. the result should display without any search button

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you edit your question and provide code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#city-select").change(function() {
  //get array of values for 2nd select using $(this).val();
  var result_area = ["area1", "area2"];

  //get array of values for 3rd select using $(this).val(); 
  var result_spec =  ["specialization1", "specialization2"]; 

  $.each(result_area, function(item) {
    $("#area-select").append($("<option />").val(item).text(item));
  });
  $.each(result_spec, function(item) {
    $("#specialization-select").append($("<option />").val(item).text(item));
  });
});
```